# Dropbox chooser in an iframe

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to open dropbox chooser in an iframe.

I've followed [the doc](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js) to integrate chooser in my application, but when clicking on the chooser button it opens in a browser window.

I've seen some applications which opens Dropbox chooser within their application in a modal popup. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is technically possible, but we (Dropbox) need to specifically allow it for your app. By default, nothing on dropbox.com will allow itself to be put in an iframe for security reasons. (E.g. take a look at "clickjacking.")

We usually won't change that policy, but we do sometimes make exceptions for larger customers who we can work with directly on the security implications.