# Open dropbox chooser into jQuery popup instead of window

Tags: popup, dropbox-api

In asana.com you can see that chooser opens in popup modal but I am unable to do it as my client also wants it to open in jQuery popup. Everything is working fine, I have implemented chooser in my project but only thing is that it opens in new window but client wants it in jQuery popup, and I have tried few things but nothing works i get this error if i try to use api version 1 as asana website is doing

Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'Deny'.

So I am using api v2, everything works, I just can't get it to open in popup and client is stuck to same.

Any help would be appreciated.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropbox chooser in an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349795/dropbox-chooser-in-an-iframe)

Comment: Okay, so i need to contact dropbox support for that, and see if they can help.